# How to use Schema Registry API to check schema compatibility

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#sr-api-compatibility

How can I use the Schema Registry API to check schema compatibility when the schema is dependent on types defined in separate files?

I've tried concatenating the files and posting as per the example but to no avail.

```
POST /compatibility/subjects/test/versions/latest HTTP/1.1
Host: schemaregistry.example.com
Accept: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json, application/vnd.schemaregistry+json, application/json

{
  "schema": // <-- I need to include multiple .avsc files here
    "{
       \"type\": \"record\",
       \"name\": \"test\",
       \"fields\":
         [
           {
             \"type\": \"string\",
             \"name\": \"field1\"
           },
           {
             \"type\": \"int\",
             \"name\": \"field2\"
           }
         ]
     }"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Kafka record schemas themselves don't have "separate files" (or files at all), so you need to build the full schema as such, by nesting record types.

Simplest way, IMO, is to use [Avro IDL](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/idl.html) files, then `avro-tools.jar` or the Maven plugin to create your (combined) AVSC files, then you can also use the Schema Registry Maven plugin's compatibility goal (assuming you're using Java)

Comment: This is for an existing codebase where each record type schema is in a separate .avsc file, they aren't nested. I'm just asking how to combine them for this API call.

Comment: Turns out you can just concat the definitions into a json list ["def-one-json", "def-two-json"] but individual schemas must be defined before the schemas that import them, it doesn't look ahead, just 500's.

Comment: Last I checked, then compatibility endpoint doesn't accept lists, but it does accept a `references` field (although, I have never tried it). I don't understand what you're trying to do if the AVSC files don't refer to fields within one or the other (edit your question to show what is in the registry and your files, and the response you expect for those files)... If you have separate files, they would be separate schemas, and need to be POST-ed separately

Comment: Schema needed to be fully expanded, eg instead of {"type": "com.example.Widget"}, "type": { /*full-definition-here*/ }, which seems to work.

It did accept the 'sub-definitions' as a list but always reported compatibility which was a little misleading.

Thanks for looking!